# How do i divide by an Alias?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When I run the follwing query I get a ORA- 00937 error.

```
select apex_utilities.get_invtype(o_code)
,count(c.id) as "Case Count"
,round(sum(billable_time/3600),2) as "Time(hrs)"
,round(sum(billable_time/count(c.id)),2) as "AHT(secs)"
from        myTable c
where c.date_created between :p31_period_start and add_months(:p31_period_start,1)
group by rollup(apex_utilities.get_invtype(o_code));
```

If I comment out the line

```
    ,round(sum(billable_time/count(c.id)),2) as "AHT(secs)"
```

it runs as expected, without this column appearing.

How do i get it to run including this line? If I add billable_time to the group by then the output is incorrect as I get many rows as it groups all the billable_time as well as the invtype. In addition i have to remove the 'SUM' from the line to get it to run.

The output I am looking for is similar to the following

```
invtype    CaseCount    Time(Hrs)    AHT(secs)
CDCW          1234       308:53:45   909.56
CBCB          100        24:56:34    109.24
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you want is actually:

```
 ,round(sum(billable_time)/count(c.id),2) as "AHT(secs)"`
```

I suspect it's balking because you are aggregating inside an aggregation. If you truly mean to do this, then you'll probably need a subquery to get that `count(c.id)` so you can apply it inside the aggregation of `SUM(billable_time, count_of_c_id)` bit.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to move that count out into a subquery. I've done the same with the sum here for clarity:

```
 with cteTable as
 (
  select apex_utilities.get_invtype(o_code) invtype
        ,count(c.id)                        casecount
        ,sum(billable_time)                 totaltime
    from myTable c
   where c.date_created between :p31_period_start and add_months(:p31_period_start,1)
group by rollup(apex_utilities.get_invtype(o_code))
 )
 select invtype 
       ,casecount                    "Case Count"
       ,round(totaltime/3600,2)      "Time(hrs)"
       ,round(totaltime/casecount,2) "AHT(secs)"
   from cteTable;
```